# Showstopper bug: MSE+MathJax unusable for 6 months with Chrome

Tags: support, bug, status-norepro

For roughly six months or so, since around the latest MathJax deployment, the site has been highly unstable using recent Chrome versions (17-22) on Windows 7. I see guaranteed page freezes composing answers of nontrivial length, "Aw Snap" browser crashes, etc. I have lost *much* work while composing answers due to this serious bug. I cannot recall any other software problem in recent memory that has proved more frustrating. The bug seems to be specific to MSE/MathJax since Chrome is rock-solid on all other sites I visit.

I've been waiting patiently for a fix, but it appears that there is none forthcoming (there has been no official response from SE). Could SE folks please give some indication whether or not resources will be allocated to fix this showstopper bug?  Given that Chrome is one of the browsers with highest market share (being generally fastest - as it is on MSE), we may end up losing members if the site does not function stably in Chrome.

Is anyone using Chrome 18 not encountering these problems? If so, perhaps as a community we can troubleshoot the problem and devise workarounds.

**Update** Thanks to zyx for reminding me in the comments that Eric Naslund [reported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/124049/157951) a similar bug March 1 on MSO. Then we both were using Chrome 17, so the bug isn't specific to Chrome 18.

Similar freezes [were reported on MO](http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/1336/chrome-crash/) when MathJax 2 was deployed there (March 22). This seems to confirm my hunch that the problems were introduced by MathJax 2.0.

I have added some answers to poll Chrome  usage to help determine if the bug is specific to browser or browser+OS or some more specific context. I suspect that the bug may not be widely reported here since the majority of users here may be using Firefox. However, even if so, Chrome is well on its way to gaining leading market share generally (see stats below), so if the site is broken in Chrome, the majority of users who encounter MSE through web search results may have major problems accessing the site.

[image]

Comment: I think the bug is specific to MathJax since it also happens to me on MO. So I think the MathJax people are the right people to complain to, not the SE people.

Comment: Had you reported this problem elsewhere? (FWIW, I do not see any such problem using Firefox)

Comment: No problem. Firefox **v.11** (thanks to Jeff Atwood for recommending I upgrade from v. 3!)

Comment: @Mariano Is there a better replace to report it? Since SE claims to support Mathjax, indeed partnering with the entity behind MathJax, providing funding etc, I presume that SE is the correct entity to report to. Moreover, the bug is probably specific to the way MathJax is integrated on SE.

Comment: Yes, this bug has bitten me too. However, I think this issue is specific to chrome.

Comment: @Qiaochu This is *not* the same *occasional* crash that appears in other browsers. Using Chrome 18 one gets a *guaranteed* freeze if one composes an answer of any nontrivial length. Further, it completely crashes Chrome in some cases.

Comment: @BillDubuque, this is the correct place to report it. But since you wrote that you have been waiting a couple of months for the fix I wondered if you had reported this earlier to SE somewhere else: otherwise they might not even be aware of the problem!

Comment: @Mariano No, I didn't report it anywhere else (nor should I be required to). I mentioned it here a few times in comments when others reported similar problems. Generally, when reporting bugs, it is not a good idea to circumvent product support channels. The problem could be in SE code, not MathJax code. It is SE's job to diagnose it and, if need be, relay it to MathJax support. End users should not have to do so.

Comment: You are not required, but neither is anyone required to read all the comments chasing for what should have been more obviously reported. It should be obvious that the *product support channel* **is** this meta site...

Comment: @Mariano Which I why I reported it on meta, in comments and now a question. SE claims to monitor all metas for bug reports, right?

Comment: I emphatically suggest that next time you or anyone comes across a problem so serious that it can be considered it to be a showstopper bug, you skip the comments step and post it as soon as possible as a question here on meta. I am pretty sure you could have saved a couple of months of having the show stopped that way.

Comment: @Mariano The bug has already been reported a handful of times (as recently as yesterday by Norbert). But there is not yet any report of fixes, status, etc by anyone claiming to represent SE. It seems that SE is not aware of how serious this problem is for Chrome users. Hence my post.

Comment: Can you provide links to those reports?

Comment: @Mariano That is not my job.

Comment: OK. I'll just ignore this thread.

Comment: Why would MathJax be the culprit, when the severe problems only appear with Chrome? I'm using FF, and I don't get that kind of problems.

Comment: @Jyrki It's impossible to answer that without knowing the way MathJax is integrated with SE. But since Chrome 18 is solid on hundreds of other sites I visit, it's likely that the bug is not in Chrome.

Comment: @Mariano It's your prerogative to ignore whatever you like. That doesn't help fix the bug. It's not my responsibility to do bug tracking for SE, nor should moderators be posting silly remarks like the above implying that members should do so. I don't find your above comments very welcoming.

Comment: FWIW, I think you're conflating *genuine requests for information* with *imposition of duty (job) or responsibility*, Bill. I agree with *what* you are saying, but it's as if you're having a conversation with a different Mariano than I see here in the commentary.

Comment: @TheChaz Alas, in the past Mariano and I haven't seen eye-to-eye on some matters, and, unfortunately, as much as we (both?) try, it still manages to affect some of our current interactions. But thanks for your moderations efforts.

Comment: Well to your (plural) credit, the conversation has been civil! I'll butt-out now...

Comment: p.s. Vote "The Chaz" for MSE moderator 2012!!!

Comment: @The Chaz, the words "reported ... as recently as yesterday by Norbert" *are* a link, and can be evaluated to a URL in a few seconds by anyone who genuinely wants that information.

Comment: @zyx, (it evaluates to a link, namely http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4029/, to something that appeared here *yesterday*, yet the problem seems to have existed for two months; the tone of your comment might seem to hint that someone was not genuinely wanting that information, and someone might not appreciate that)

Comment: @BillDubuque 1. If Chrome crashes, then there is a bug in Chrome. This doesn't imply that there isn't also a bug in MathJax or in the Stack Exchange code, but Chrome is not supposed to crash whatever a web page throws at it. 2. A Stack Exchange bug report is a *question* on a Meta site (such as [meta.math.se]) tagged [meta-tag:bug]. A comment has no [meta-tag:bug] and so is not a bug report. The oldest [bug report about Chrome 18](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bbug%5D+%2Bchrome+%2B18) concerning crashes I can see here is [yesterday's](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/4029).

Comment: @Mariano   I do think that evaluating the link and citing the result (if that does not suffice to answer whatever you wished to know) is the first necessary step when making any requests for additional material.  Investing a few more seconds such as typing "Chrome" into the search box turns up unresolved bug reports going back... two months, to early March and (implicitly) the middle of February.  It appears that Bill was correct in his assertions, and if there is any task force working on this at SE they have kept it secret. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124049/

Comment: I find it absurd that someone who may have information relevant to a problem s/he wants to have fixed (like relevant reports) at the same time may think that it is better to withhold that information. If there are extant reports on the issue, starting a new thread on the matter only increases the noise and then it should simply be closed. I invest much more than two seconds already on this site: it seems absurd to me that if you or anyone *already has* the information in question, you do not simply provide it instead of giving dismissive instructions to «type into the search box».

Comment: At the moment, I do not see what purpose this thread has, as by at least two accounts there are already several reports on the matter and there have in fact been for months now. Any new reporting of information should happen on those reports: nothing will be gained by scattering the relevant data *even more*.

Comment: @Mariano Nothing was "withheld". If you search for the prior threads (I haven't saved the links) you will find exchanges between I and SE folks (Geoff, David, etc) on a number of occasions. This bug still exists for me. It's probably the worst bug I've encountered in decades online. That's why I am reporting it now in this question, hopefully more clearly, and hopefully collecting more data of use for troubleshooting, whether by developers or the community.

Comment: @Downvoters What is the point of downvoting a bug report??? The mind boggles...

Comment: @BillDubuque:  I am not SE folks, I am MathJax.  It is also not true that no work has been done to address this issue.  It was originally reported during the [MathJax 2.0 beta stage](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/3581/7798), and after the v2.0 official release at the end of February, I worked on a rewrite of the preview code hoping to resolve this issue (and the delay issue as well).  That was not successful in eliminating this issue with Chrome.  I have not been able to reproduce it myself, so it is difficult for me to diagnose it.

Comment: As Gilles points out, "Aw Snap" represents a bug in Chrome regardless of whether it is triggered by something SE or MathJax does.  Just because Chrome hasn't crashed for you on other sites doesn't mean it isn't a Chrome bug.  The trigger is undoubtedly the heavy javascript/DOM work done during the preview, and it is probably due to some interaction between the preview code, MathJax, and the DOM modifications that are being made.  Personally, I think it is because the DOM is being replaced by the editor while MathJax is still working on it, but that is just a guess.

Comment: @David The "Aw Snap" crashes are much less common than the freezes. The source of such crashes need not be bugs in Chrome. Can you release the code so I can debug it?

Comment: @BillDubuque, I respectfully disagree: "Aw Snap" represents a bug no matter what caused it, just as MathJax's "[Math Processing Error]" always represents a bug in MathJax, as they are the results of uncaught exceptions within the code.  A freeze is also a bug in my opinion, but that is a bit more ambiguous.  In any case, you already *have* the code, since it is sent to your browser every time you use the site.  The code that I wrote is [here](http://cdn.sstatic.net/js/mathjax-editing-new.js).  Knock yourself out.  PS, my name is "Davide" not "David".

Comment: @Davide Thanks. My point was simply that even though the bug manifests itself as a Chrome freeze/crash, the true source of the bug may well be external to Chrome, e.g. an error in a callback to some external module, e.g. MathJax.  Of course in perfectly designed software such external bugs would be appropriately trapped and handled, but rarely - if ever - is any software so perfect.

Comment: @Davide Did something change today (or in last 7 days) in MSE's MathJax? I'm using a laptop today (on the road) and MathJax rendering is *very* slow, and sometimes fails to display all LaTeX output, both in IE and FF. I don't recall ever seeing this before on this laptop (it is very fast).

Comment: Could the person who voted to close as "not a real question" please explain. Bug reports are on-topic on meta.

Comment: @BillDubuque, nothing has changed on the MathJax CDN.  I don't know of any changes on the SE sites, but I am not in the loop for those and only find out when they are announced here.  You may be getting a slower network connection than you are used to when you are on the road.  Hotel networks are notoriously bad in my experience, for example.

Comment: Also happening with Chrome 19

Comment: Confirmed on Chrome 22.

Comment: @BillDubuque Don't whther this workaround will help you but I resolve my issue with Aw snap by the following cheat. I write my answers in Ask Question window. Even if Aw snap occurs all the text remains and I continue writing.

Comment: @Norbert I suspect you are employing the SE draft feature (which also works for answers). However, that in itself is often unreliable (and is limited to one draft per Q,A). Also, often I get not only Aw Snap crashes but a complete Chrome crash, which requires a Chrome restart. This causes losses not only on MSE but also other sites.

Comment: @BillDubuque sometimes I get BSOD, so don't think that your issue the worst possible.

Comment: @Norbert I haven't seen any BSODs from browsers on Win7 (but I do recall some on XP). You may find  Nirsoft's BlueScreenView helpful in locating the culprit.

Comment: Still crashing (a lot) in my Chrome 23.0.1271.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, I have  major problems browsing MSE with Chrome recently.

Please upvote (don't downvote!) this answer if you have made significant use of Chrome to browse the MSE main site in the past couple of months with many freezes or crashes (Aw Snap!). Please add a comment mentioning your OS, Chrome version, and any other contextual information that may prove useful for debugging purposes.

Comment: system - Windows 7, hint - sometimes text restored sometimes not

Comment: Windows 7, Chrome-18.0.1025.162; "Aw Snap!"s often--No information is saved when I edit. They get saved if I am composing the answer. And, this seems to happen because of the frequent flickering of TeX.

Comment: Believe it or not, someone downvoted this poll answer. So much for trying to conduct an *honest* poll.

Comment: I feel that they fail to understand what a poll means. There is also a downvote in the previous answer.

Comment: @Kannappan Perhaps, so I've added "don't downvote".

Comment: I don't quite understand the upvotes on the comments.  Is that someone saying "me too" for that comment?  If so, are they not upvoting the answer?  The answer (currently) has two upvotes, but there are a total of four upvotes on the comments, so I'm confused about how many people reporting this problem that represents.

Comment: @DavideCervone: This answer is +3-1, so I'd say that the 3 upvotes matches up to the 3 comment-upvotes on Kannappan Sampath's comment.

Comment: @David Please note that this answer has 3 upvotes (someone downvoted it for some strange reason). So, currently, including I, there are at least 4 Chrome users encountering this problem. Since the reports on the alternative are all on Macs, it seems that, so far, everyone using Chrome on Windows 7 encounters the bug, which agrees with my experience on a handful of Windows 7 machines. To reproduce it usually requires an answer of at least a couple paragraphs, with nontrivial MathJax, and some amount of editing.

Comment: @Isaac and Bill:  Sorry, I can only see the total of 2 — I don't know how to see the ups and downs separately.  But in any case, doesn't a 1 upvote mean *two* people (the original poster and the upvoter) and a 3 mean *four* people?  So the comments have 6 but the answer has only 5 (Bill's answer, plus the 4 votes — 3 up and 1 down, assuming the down vote was meant as an up).  It still seems out of whack to me.

Comment: @David Yes, I mentioned the downvote precisely because I knew that you don't have the rep to see it.  There are no votes from me (authors cannot vote on their own posts). I don't know what the comment votes signify. They could be bug reports or not.

Comment: chrome 18 is *extremely* buggy, for the record, not just with MathJax rendering but in lots of other ways I've seen. It's the buggiest release I have encountered in Chrome to date. I actually might recommend switching over to Firefox (or Safari.. maybe even IE9) until they get this worked out.

Comment: @Jeff As I said, the freezes/crashes also occur in Chrome 17, released Feb. 8. I'm not aware of any feedback on MathJax 2.0 on earlier Chrome versions, but that might be useful to know for troubleshooting purposes. Why was MJ2 deployed without any (alpha/beta) testing? Many users lost valuable work due to these crashes. This is not a nice way to support members who volunteer many thousands of hours of their time here. Can we expect better support in the future?

Comment: Just a note: this used to happen on Phy.SE for me as well. But I use chrome canary, so I get bugs and bugfixes early :)

Comment: Still lots (LOTS) of "Aw Snap" problems here, with Chrome 18.0.1025.168, Win-7. This, together with the other (unrelated?) bug of "Show math -> As text" (also, only with Chrome) is a pain.

Comment: @leonbloy You might want to try the extension mentioned in Davide's answer (I haven't been able to test it yet).

Comment: @Manishearth: does "used to happen" mean that you are no longer experiencing the problem?

Comment: @DavideCervone: I _thought_ so. As in it stopped happening. But it happened again yesterday on chem.SE. :/

Comment: @Manishearth: Sorry to hear you continue to have the problem. Do you work with multiple tabs open and leave the browser running all the time, or do you restart it regularly?

Comment: @DavideCervone: Multiple tabs open, yes (the whole site dies if one page does). I restart it regularly, though :/

Comment: @Manishearth: When you say "the whole site dies" does that mean that viewing any page for the site causes a lock up or "Aw Snap", or only when you try to edit?  And does that apply to new tabs as well as old ones?  And in old tabs without reloading them?  Since javascript in one window isn't supposed to be able to affect that in another, it sounds like it might be the cache is getting corrupted (memory management issues).  Can you try clearing the cache and reloading the tab to see if that helps?  (I don't remember if Chrome also needs a restart to really clear the cache; some browsers do.)

Comment: @DavideCervone: Well, refresh fixes it, but all tabs of that site (whether or not in the same window I don't know) show "Aw, Snap". I think that's expected behavior in Chrome for crashes. New tabs/refreshes work fine. I'll try clearing the cache, but I'm not sure how that will help catching the bug--it's unpredictable anyway :/. By the way, let's continue the discussion here: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3428/mathjax-showstopper-bug

Comment: This is happening a lot to me (Chrome 19, Win7), and usually, when re-editing an existing post, I loose all my editing. For what's worth: the crash also makes crash all other windows of MSE. Today I had opened the little window  "MathJax Equation Source" and it too showed the "Aw, Snap!" after the crash.

Comment: This has not happened to me on chrome, here using ubuntu 14.04, this might be a windows only problem as I havent ben able to find reports of non windows users in these comments.

Answer (score 2):

No, I have no major problems browsing MSE with Chrome recently.

Please upvote (don't downvote!) this answer if you have made significant use of Chrome to browse the MSE main site in the past couple of months without many freezes or crashes (Aw Snap!). Please add a comment mentioning your OS, Chrome version any other contextual information that may prove useful for debugging purposes.

Comment: Note: If you don't have any problems, *please* do comment with context: browser, OS, versions, etc. It would be very useful to determine a known working configuration.

Comment: I'll refrain from voting since I haven't really used the site as heavily lately, but I've had no trouble with MathJax (here or elsewhere) + Chrome 17-18-19 on OSX (10.6).

Comment: I haven't had any trouble with Chrome, mostly on Mac.  But I'm not sure I have written any answers of 'non-trivial length'.

Comment: I didn't vote on this because I thought it was specifically directed to Chrome users.

Answer (score 2):

I am still unable to reproduce the problem that you all are having.  I seem to be able to type answers for five minutes of pretty much constant typing in Chrome 18 on Windows 7 with no sign of a crash.  I'm wondering if there is some other common factor among those who are experiencing the problem.  E.g., some extension, or lots of open tabs, or some optional system component or something.

I still think that the most likely trigger for the problem is that the preview editor can replace the contents of the preview while MathJax is still processing it (meaning MathJax may try to process math that is no longer there).  When I rewrote the preview code, I tried to minimize the time that that was possible, but did not eliminate it entirely, so that is still my primary concern.

Other possibilities include memory management problem within Chrome (e.g., reusing memory that has already been freed), or garbage collection problems, or other such issues.  The preview/MathJax combination does put a very heavy burden on the browser, and if there are memory problems, that could likely bring them out.

To test my hypothesis concerning the replacement of the preview while MathJax is still running, I have put together a Greasemonkey script that replaces the current MathJax preview code with a modified version that prevents the editor from pulling the DOM out from under MathJax while it is still typesetting.  (It does this by making a second copy of the preview, which is the one that MathJax works on, and that is updated only when MathJax is guaranteed to be finished with it.  The editor is free to replace the other at any time it sees fit).

If those of you who are experiencing the problem would like to help diagnose it, please install [this extension](http://www.math.union.edu/locate/Cervone/transfer/mathjax/mathjaxMSEpreview.user.js) and try out editing to see if that improves the situation or not.  It will affect only the math.stackechange.com and meta.math.stackexchange.com sites, and you can tell that this extension is operating if you see that the border of the preview is blue rather than grey.

The userscript actually works in Firefox, Safari (with GreaseKit), and Opera as well as Chrome (I haven't tried it in IE), but the real interest is in whether it fixes the Chrome issue.  The timing of when this code runs is critical (since it must intercept the StackExchange code at just the right time in order to install itself properly); unfortunately, the Safari and Opera implementations of userscripts are somewhat variable in the timing of when they run, so it is possible with those browsers that the script misses the window of opportunity and can't install itself correctly.  If that happens, reloading the page usually resolves the problem.  (Opera pretty much always misses the first time through a page, but works on a reload.)

Please leave a comment here concerning your luck with this extension if you try it out.  Remember that this is experimental code, so you may want to disable or remove it once you are done trying it out.

**Aside**:  I am also working on an incremental previewer that only updates the paragraph that you are editing rather than the entire answer.  That should help with longer posts with lots of math.  This is a much more complicated prospect, however, since you have to get things like references (`\label{}` and `\ref{}`) and macro definitions (`\def` and `\newcommand`) to work incrementally as well, forcing updates in other parts of the answer when they are needed due to changes in the current paragraph.  If this experiment with userscripts goes well, I will make the incremental preview available for testing in a similar way, and then offer it to the StakeExchange folks once any kinks are worked out.

Comment: Lots of open tabs here, anywere between 30-90 I'd guess. And they can stay open for over a month, with partial drafts of answers. I'm not surprised that it takes some nontrivial context to reproduce since I don't usually see it right away. But once it starts occurring it never stops. I'm not using any extensions.

Comment: Could it possibly be related to running out of some resource when so many tabs are open? E.g. maybe some GC bug (failure to properly reclaim some resource) eventually causes large long-running sessions to run out of the resource, causing MathJax to freeze?

Comment: I knew you used a lot of tabs; I was curious if others did as well.  Sure, using so many long-lived tabs certainly can cause problems.  If there is a memory management issue (a memory leak for example) that could very well cause you to run out of memory.  And if there are memory re-use problems (re-using freed memory), the longer the processes run, and the more of them there are, the more likely that will become a problem.  So yes, you are operating in a fashion that is most likely to be adversely affected by those kinds of issues.

Comment: The fact that when a problem occurs in one window it affects the results in other windows or other pages in teh same window ("once it starts occurring it never stops") suggests a memory problem.

Comment: I'm wondering if you are planning to try the extension that I have offered to see if that helps you out?

Comment: Yes, I plan to try it sometime in the next day or two (I can't risk a crash at the moment). Do I need to reboot and/or restart Chrome to properly test it? Ditto for removing it? Thanks much for looking into it.

Comment: You do not need to reboot the computer.  Technically, you do not need to restart the browser (but would need to reload any page where you wanted to try it).  But if the problem you are having really is a memory issue, then not restarting the browser may mean that the memory problems are still in play, and so would not be a fair test.  So I would recommend restarting the browser.  You can try it initially without a restart, but having a crash under those circumstances would not seem very conclusive to me.

Comment: Ok, that's what I figured. And what about removing it? Does disabling it do the trick or should the browser be restarted to be sure.

Comment: No problem.  When removing it, you don't need to reboot.  Things should go back to the original editor for any new page you open or old one you reload.

Comment: Ok, I'll let you know asap if I can reproduce it with the extension. I don't recall typically how long it took from browser start to reproduce it - could be a day, could be a week. But I'll use Chrome exclusively to try to trigger it asap.

Comment: OK, thanks.  I await your results, and those of anyone else who wants to give it a try.

Comment: Btw, here's one other data point. Sometimes I restart Chrome from a saved session after a Win7 reboot. This means that it quickly reloads many tabs, often over 100, many with MathJax. Could that be causing problems for MathJax, with *many* tabs attempting to render simultaneously? Perhaps problems that don't manifest immediately?

Comment: Not that would be causing the crashes that you see.  It potentially could cause MathJax to time out waiting for files or fonts since all the instances of MathJax are competing against each other for network bandwidth, and MathJax's timeout times are relatively short (15 seconds).  So some copies of MathJax might give up on some files and go on without them, leading to "Math Processing Errors" later on.  But you are definitely pushing the limits, I would imagine.

Comment: Yes, I do get many such errors, but all seems well after refreshing the wedged pages. Of course I have no idea if all is well under the hood, which is why I thought it worth mention. But I'm fairly sure I also had the problems in non-saved-sessions too.

Comment: @DavideCervone, big thanks, i will try it out.

Comment: With the extension (blue borders checked) I still had crashes with Chrome 18 in Win-XP

Comment: @leonbloy:  Thanks for the info, though it is disappointing.  Do you use many tabs open at once, and do you restart your browser regularly?  (I'm trying to establish any pattern among the users, since I'm not able to reproduce it myself, and I know that Bill's workflow follows that pattern.)  Also, did you restart Chrome after installing, or just reload the page?

Comment: @DavideCervone: it's really difficult to reproduce. perhaps it's related to a long editing session (lots of edits of a fairly complex post). i've experienced the crash with no extra tab, and after restarting the machine.

Comment: @leonbloy:  I appreciate the extra data.  It sounds more and more like a memory management issue to me.  Unfortunately, those are notoriously difficult to isolate, and it probably isn't something that MathJax can solve, except indirectly by changing its memory usage patterns.  But any attempt on my part to do that would just be shooting in the dark, and the chances of hitting on the right circumstances are pretty slim.

Comment: Same problem still happening often to me, with the extension, with Chrome 19. Sometimes loses the edited text, sometimes not.

Answer (score 1):

I am writing this answer to bring to light another strange behavior I noticed today. This bug appears related to this one and so I don't think this warrants a new question post:

> I was editing an answer. **That window "Aw!Snap"ped and every other Stack exchange window, (two Math.SE windows and a chat stack exchange window) died.** This is a good enough evidence in my opinion that Chrome is not the trouble maker.

But, well, I am not a Tech Savvy to comment on this issue, but this behaviour looks relevant to this bug and I have brought it here for the SE team.

Hope we can get this fixed at the earliest.

**Edit:** I had this happen to me again today! The time of this can be had from my comment below!

Comment: I had it the second time today. It is aweful!!

Comment: If Chrome is flawless, why do you think Firefox users are not seeing this bug? A conspiracy against Chrome?

Comment: Dear @JyrkiLahtonen, I did not write that others are not facing this difficulty in my post. I don't use FF much and therefor am largely clueless. I am sorry if I miscommunicated something. Please feel free to edit out anything as such. Regards,

Comment: You have no reason to apologize. It is just that when people praise Google, I will start grinding my axe. On a good day I may just look the other way, but on a bad day ...